# How to use FBSDKShareAPI for pages and groups

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

Background:  I have working code that uses FBSDKGraphRequest to post "stories" (links + pics + text) to a user's timeline, groups and pages.  For the groups and pages, the posts are made by specifying (as an example) /{group-id}/feed as the Open Graph node to post to, and using the correct access token.

I've already dealt with app reviews, permissions, and access tokens and everything works.

But now I am attempting to move to the FBSDKShareKit methods, that allow the definition of objects, actions, and content.  However, I can't find any way to specify the desired graph path to share to, or access token to use.  FBSDKShareAPI defaults to the user's feed and I can't find any mechanism to modify that.  Does anyone have any insight on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

My bad -- an old "header search path" was causing an earlier version of the share API header file to be displayed/used.  Once I cleaned that up, I could access the most up-to-date version, which has graphPath and AccessToken properties on the FBSDKShareAPI object.